# Thunderbird does not move deleted files to 'deleted' folder

Tags: thunderbird

NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"

Linux version 5.4.0-122-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-095)
(gcc version 9.4.0 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)) #138-Ubuntu
SMP Wed Jun 22 15:00:31 UTC 2022

I'm using Thunderbird 91.11.0 64 bit

Without my interference, Deleted mails disappear, they do NOT go to the 'Deleted' folder.

In trying to correct this anomaly, I have followed procedures but am asked to visit the Thunderbird:
Account Settings -> Server Settings
Where I am told, I may select my deleted folder or even rename it, but that option is neither mentioned or available anywhere that I have been able to search in Thunderbird menus.

Other referencec suggest that the Trash and Trash.msf entries are to be deleted and then either Tbird will recreate them or, if not, I have to create a file in the correct directory, named 'Trash'. This doesn't end the problem either.
Any and all help gratefully received.

ps Tbird recreates the Trash and Trash.msf without my help.

Chris

```
I select the messages I want to delete and then have used Tbird's 'Delete' option and also used the pull down menu, both delete the selected mail, neither move it to the 'Deleted folder, which I have also compacted.
Sadly no improvements.
```

Comment: please [edit] your question to indicate how you are deleting messages. I have the same version of TB 20.04.4 version combination and in a test, pressing the `Delete` key sent the email to the Deleted folder. Also, have you tried right click on the `Deleted` folder and selecting `Compact`which can also resolve some issues?

Comment: I also compacted as suggested, no change.

Comment: In your account settings, you can select what the delete option is suppposed to do. There are 3 possibilities: delete the messages completely (seems that's happening right now), move them to local trash folder, or move them to a real folder on the server. If you can't see your "deleted messages" folder in the folders list on the server, maybe it's because you accidentally deleted it. You should consult your mail service help how to restore it. You can of course simply create it from within Thunderbird, but it's not sure if it will be recognized properly as "trash" by your service.

Comment: You suggest that i have three options, and that I can select what the 'delete'  option is supposed to do! I have no such options available to me!

Comment: I have discovered that I can drag a mail and drop it in the 'Deleted' folder, and it actually goes there although that folder does not give a tally of what it contains and still appears 'greyed' out.